# OpenGL ES 2.0 book, bottom of pg. 95:

Tags: opengl-es

I don't get this concept at all:

> ...you should not use more uniforms or
>   varyings than would exceed the minimum
>   allowed storage sizes after packing.

Shouldn't that be 'maximum'?  (Or conversely 'less'?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be maximum, it's just a mistake, but it doesn't appear in the errata: http://opengles-book.com/errata.html

Assuming it's that book you're talking about.